# Substring method not working with API data

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$("#billing_myfield16").val([data.dossiernummer]);
```

Via an API i auto fill the field with the ID `#billing_myfield16`. This code works perfectly fine so dont worry about that. The problem is, I just want the first 3 characters of whatever is stored in `[data.dossiernummer]`. The following code did not work for me.

```
$("#billing_myfield16").val([data.dossiernummer].substring(0,4) );
```

It didnt work.

Comment: What is `[data.dossiernummer]` supposed to be? It looks like an array to me, which does not have a substring method... Maybe `data.dossiernummer` is the string you are looking for?

Comment: *"It didnt work"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement. What did it do? What errors were thrown in console? That error should be  big clue

Comment: Can we see the value of data.dossiernummer? Also, try to code in English, even though you're Dutch ;)

Comment: `"".substring(0,3)`? The second argument is the index of the first character to exclude from the returned substring :)

Answer (score 0):

So I made a mistake in my attempt.

Instead of `$("#billing_myfield16").val([data.dossiernummer].substring(0,4) );`

I should have done

```
$("#billing_myfield16").val([data.dossiernummer.substring(0,3)]);
```

Which makes sense, seeing `data.dossiernummer` contains the string i'm trying to substract.

Comment: This would return the first 4 characters. Also, you don't need the square brackets when setting the value.